# Django server and prestodb connection and data pagination

Tags: django, database, caching, presto

I have a simple infrastructure that is using django server for APIs and PrestoDb as query engine. Everything is working fine for me but I have few limitations depending on prestodb:

- Prestodb doesn't support pagination, How can I manage huge amount of data? loading it into memory is costly.
- I am opening and closing connection to presto again and again for each query, What is the best way to use only one or two connections only and use them all over the application?
- What is the proper way to show errors to users instead of raw presto exceptions?
- What kind of caching mechanism should be used for common data?
- I am using celery for background jobs, is there any other for running background jobs that are not load on python server?
- What are best practices for django? Any helpful link?

Answer (score 2):

The question is very broad, so let me answer only the part about pagination.

Presto does support pagination via SQL Standard `OFFSET m FETCH NEXT n ROWS ONLY` syntax, or with `OFFSET m LIMIT n` simplified syntax.

You can read more about this in the blog post https://trino.io/blog/2020/02/03/beyond-limit-presto-meets-offset-and-ties.html

Of course, this is suitable mostly for ad-hoc queries, or when you do not have option to improve the actual query structure. For scheduled queries, or queries that are part of some workflow (not ad-hoc), it is recommended to use query predicates (where relevant) instead of OFFSET. See more at https://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/partial-results/fetch-next-page.

Answer (score 1):

First off, Presto isn't made for transactional purposes, but for analytical ones, usually having large amount of data. In case of transactional, a MySql/Postgres connected by Django ORM/Models is a better choice.

- No, it doesn't. According to [here](https://github.com/prestodb/presto/issues/7636) and [here](https://github.com/prestodb/presto/issues/2661) you have to fetch all data, cache it in the backend and query that. The query/filter should be very particular in order to get a small amount of data of interest. For example consider adding a date filter and limiting it to a few days/months. This way you constrain your users not to do heavy queries.
- You can reuse the same connection if you don't need different configurations, like transaction isolation level
- Regarding the DB error, just return an Response with 500 code an Internal error message. Also make sure to log the stacktrace
- Django has a [caching framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/cache/) out of the box
- Celery is a good choice, it usually goes with Redis or RabbitMQ. These services are deployed separately of the main Django app
- [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/) should be a good start

Comment: Thank you for the reply, 

What do you mean by fetch all and cache it? Should I get all the data and save it in django cache?

How can I reuse the connection?. I am confused about it

I have to tell the user what went wrong, for example in case a table doesn't exists then how can I show user proper error? This is one of the case, In case of connection error I need to show another message etc.

How much data I can handle in django cache?

Celery is indeed a good choice and I m using it with redis - done

Thanks

Comment: If your query has 1000 results, fetch them all in your backend (in memory, or in a cache) and use that for further pagination queries (page 2 will bring 51-100 of that 1000, so no more going to presto while changing pages)

Comment: If you are using https://github.com/prestodb/presto-python-client for example, reuse the `conn` object.

Comment: Use does not need to know the internal structure of your application. If it is not a user error (for example he entered a name instead of a date), he should get a generic error like "Contact your administrator with this code xxx-xxx". Then the user contacts support using that code and support will look at the logs in order to fix/solve the issue.

Comment: In memory Django cache is good for small amount of data, but you can connect it to Redis for heavy processing -> https://realpython.com/caching-in-django-with-redis/

Comment: Actually redis is a good idea. I can separate it in different container and use it for heavy caching. 

In case of exceptions only thing I am missing is proper logging, Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: I am still not sure about how to reuse connection in all django apps